# Unique solution and extension of a nonlinear Cauchy problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to prove that this nonlinear ODE

\begin{cases}
x'=5 \cos(xt) -x^2 -5 \\
x(0.05)=-10
\end{cases}

has a unique solution defined in $[0.026,0.074]$, and if this solution can be extended to $t=11$.

I have tried to see if this ODE is Lipschitz to use Picard's theorem, but it's not.

Any other idea on how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Using the bounds of the cosine function you get
$$
-x^2-10\le x'\le -x^2.
$$
This can be integrated on both sides
$$
-\frac{10}{1-10(t-0.05)}\le x(t)\le -\sqrt{10}\tan(\sqrt{10}(t-0.05)+\arctan(\sqrt{10}))
$$
for $t\ge 0.05$, and with the bounds reversed for $t\le 0.05$.
This gives that the solution exists from about $-0.8466$ until about $t=0.14685$ and has diverged at some point $t^*<0.15$.

Other estimates based on $1\ge\cos(u)\ge1-\frac{u^2}2$ are also possible.

Comment: Is there a much cleaner way to solve it? And this doesn't give the same interval as the one in the question.

Comment: Then you should have formulated in your question that you are looking for bounds like in the standard version of the Picard-Lindelöf theorem, that is, an rectangle $R$ of $|t-0.05|\le a$, $|x+10|\le b$, then a bound on the right side $|-5(1-\cos(tx))-x^2|\le M$ on $R$ and its $x$-Lipschitz condition $|5t\sin(tx)-2x|\le L$ and then determine an interval length $h\le a$ with the conditions of the theorem $Mh\le b$ and $Lh<1$.